# Null Reference List(of String)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Hi I'm working on an SQL query function and I have been stopped in my tracks.

My code:

```
 Function insertData(ByVal conString As String, ByVal sqlType As String, ByRef tblName As String, ByRef columns() As String, ByRef params() As String)
        Dim syntax As String
        Dim tempString As String
        Dim addParam As List(Of String)

        Try
            For Each col As String In columns
                tempString = "@" & col & ", "
                addParam.Add(tempString)
            Next

            Select Case sqlType
                Case "Insert"
                    syntax = "INSERT INTO " & tblName & "(" & Join(columns, ", ") & ") VALUES (" & addParam.ToString() & ")"
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex, vbOK)
        End Try


        Return syntax
    End Function
```

The problem is:
addParam.Add(tempString) where the null object reference occurs.

I also have the issue of:

> Variable 'addParam' is used before it has been assigned a value. A
>   null reference exception could result at runtime.

Which prompts a Null Reference error.

My last error is:

> Variable 'addParam' is used before it has been assigned a value.

My eyes are glazing over I've been coding all day.

Thanks for any help.

NOTE: The function is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate the List before you use it:

```
Dim addParam As New List(Of String)
```

Comment: Oh god I swear I did that once. Thank you, Rick.

Any chance of one last query?
The generated query looks like so: 
"...VALUES(System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String])"
How would I add the @ symbol before the addParam, I know to use:
Join(addParam, ", ") to add a comma. Any to place both a comma and an @?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz  I don't know the answer to your other question but if it were me, i would avoid building a string like you're doing.  You are opening yourself up to SQL injection.  You should look at using Parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've looked at the documentation within the link and I still need to create a string with @VALUES and then utilise them like so: 

adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", _
        SqlDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID") 

Also all data is cleaned and validated before entry. Ah well I appreciate your help Rick. +1